# How to delete oldest data in table if more than 5 row using django?

Tags: python, django

If data in table more than 5 row I want to delete oldest row such as.

```
id  value
1    a1   <= delete
2    a2
3    a3
4    a4
5    a5
6    a6
```

I want to keep new 5 rows which is id 2-6 and delete oldest row which is id 1. I use this code.

```
    objects_to_keep = Data.objects.filter(key=key).order_by('id')[:5]
    Data.objects.exclude(pk__in=objects_to_keep).delete()
```

It show error like this.

```
NotSupportedError at /device/

(1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer make you delete the objects *after* the 5 first, beware.

```
# Get the 5 highest ids, note the "-id" so it's sorted descending
# The use of values_list is to provide the ids without iterating on the queryset, 
# which wont evaluated now
id_to_keep = Data.objects.filter(key=key).order_by('-id').values_list("id", flat=True)[:5]
# Now delete in one go
Data.objects.exclude(pk__in=id_to_keep).delete()
```

I suggest to keep this in the save() method so it's consistent.
If you override the save() you can use this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if Data.objects.count() > 5:
        Data.objects.first().delete()
```

PS: this wont work if you do bulk_create, as it's directly in SQL and not using save()

Edit: Ugh, I realize now that your MySql will not support the limit on some subqueries, then you should evaluate the first statement:

```
id_to_keep = list(Data.objects.filter(key=key).order_by('-id').values_list("id", flat=True)[:5])
# Now delete in one go
Data.objects.exclude(pk__in=id_to_keep).delete()
```

Answer (score -1):

try it.

```
objects_to_keep = Data.objects.filter(key=key).order_by('id')[:5]
primary_keys = [obj.pk for obj in objects_to_keep]
Data.objects.exclude(pk__in=primary_keys).delete()
```

Comment: Watch out, this solution gets the 5 **first** ids, not the 5 latest.